rename column name in the Exposed db in ktor
In my Ktor project, I have a table, called LogsTable. There is a column that I like to change its name. My database has too much data and the project is already up so I'm looking for the best option to change the table column name without major changes in schema.
My table:
object LogsTable : Table() {
    val id = integer("id").autoIncrement()
    val AudioCounts = integer("audio_counts")
    val VideoCounts = integer("video_counts")
    val timestamp = long("timestamp")

    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id)
}

let's say I want to change video_counts column to primary
